# Obtaining distribution from histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability, mean, variance

I have an array of values, with that values I plotted the histogram.I want to know the corresponding distribution from the histogram obtained. How is it possible.
Could you please explain the steps in obtaining appropriate probability distribution from histogram.

Comment: What kind of probability distribution? do you have any parametric form in mind?

Comment: If your question is how to determine the kind of statistical distribution that your data are following: It's pretty much impossible ! There is almost an infinite number of potential distribution that can fit pretty well with your histrogram.

Comment: I have an array of values and calculated mean and variance. I want to check which probability distribution is  close approximated to the histogram I obtained from the array of values. (Like I want to check if it is close to gamma,rayleigh distributions).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to ask this question in [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) as it is more about the method than the programming. However, one thing that you can do is to fit a parametric distribution (using [moment matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) or [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) for example) then compare the fitted distribution to the normalized histogram using [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) or [Bhattacharyya distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance).

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use the ["Distribution Fitting App"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/distributionfitting-app.html) in the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox.  That should help you evaluate if your data seems like it might have been drawn from some common distributions.  You may never know for sure, since multiple distributions could account for the data, but if you have a lot of data it might help you narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in many cases an eye-ball comparison is enough. With a reasonable amount of data, it is quite difficult to not be able to distinguish between a gaussian or a weibull or...

I would use [`fitdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) or [`fithist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/histfit.html) to eye-ball different distributions.

If you have no idea at all on the distribution and you want to know if two datasets are distributed differently it could be useful to compare their distributions by obtaining them with the option `'kernel'`